# How Google drive third party shortcuts work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I was reading about [third party shortcuts](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/third-party-shortcuts) in Google Drive and able to create a file in Google Drive with the sample payload mentioned in the link.

```
var fileMetadata = new File()
{
    Name = "Project plan",
    MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk"
};
var request = driveService.Files.Create(fileMetadata);
request.Fields = "id";
var file = request.Execute();
Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);
```

What I am not able to get is where can I set the external file URL here? Or how does it even work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer

*It is up to the third-party to handle the redirect to the relevant file for which a shortcut points to. This is done with the Google Drive File ID.*

#### More Information:

Google Drive shortcuts are used to link a file, the contents of which are stored elsewhere than on Drive, such as a third party web app. This isn't done through links, as Drive shortcuts contain [no content](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/third-party-shortcuts) and are made using the file metadata endpoint.

When you make a Third-party shortcut using the `Files.Create` method as you show above, the indicative information of the fact it is a shortcut is by the `application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk` mimeType, using the POST URL for inserting file metadata:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files
Authorization: <AUTHORIZATION HEADER>

{
  "title": "File's title",
  "description": "File's description",
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk"
}
```

When the shortcut is clicked, you will then get redirected to the third party web site from which the file was created - the Google Drive File ID is contained inside the `?state` query parameter, as per the [documentation on Open Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/integrate-open#app).

The important thing to know is that it is ***completely up to the third-party app/website*** to use Google Drive File ID in the `?state` parameter to match the file and content they have stored.

#### References:

- [Create a shortcut to an external file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/third-party-shortcuts)
- [Handle an Open URL](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/integrate-open#app)
- [Files: create | Google Drive API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [Configure a Drive UI Integration](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-sdk)